# Redshift: do with clauses /CMTs ALWAYS create temporary tables?

Tags: aws, redshift

I like to use "with clauses" as filters: it makes my queries more "functional" in the linearish functional programming style `x= a.b().c().filter(condition).sum()` sense (obviously, SQL is one giant functional language, it's just a bit obtuse).

If I am careful about avoiding groupings, distincts or orderings, and only use a CMT in one following query/CMT, will Redshift dispense with the temporary table, and just treat it like a filter? Monitoring seems to suggest this to be the case.

For instance, will this query create two temp tables, or will the planmer say: "hey! no need to store any data…"?

```
with FilteredList as (
          select col1, col2 from Table
          where col1 is not Null
     ),
     MoreFiltering as (
           select col1, col2 from FilteredList
           where col2 is not Nill
      )
select col1+col2 as Summo 
from MoreFiltering;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know what is going to do the planner. I would suggest to do 
`EXPLAIN`

I would say your planner will execute both CMT